# devMail.Net pop3 settings in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, pop3

first of all, I'm not a programmer and just started learning C.

One of our application which use the DevMail.Net to fetch the pop3 mail is malfunctioning as my service provider changed the pop3 port from "110" to "125". I've searched the code with "pop3" or "port" and didn't find any line defining it. I also checked the web.config in 
which on host is defined. However, in DevMail.net's mail.xml I find one entry as under:
    
      
            Default POP3 protocol port (110).
            If you need to use different port please use port parameter in  or  method.

Thank you in advance for the help.

riz1

here is the web.config config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConStr" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=email;server=172.31.2.24"/>
        <add key="ConStr3" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=123;server=172.31.2.24"/>
        <add key="ConStr2" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=abc;server=cms"/>
        <add key="host" value="pop.mail.com"/>
        <add key="username" value="contact@mail.com"/>
        <add key="password" value="Password"/>
        <add key="from" value="Help Desk"/>
        <add key="from_email" value="contact@mail.com"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a property called ".Port".

Is there an overload for the Connect method?

```
public void Connect(
    string host,
    int port
)
```

Aka

```
myobject.Connect("pop.somebody.com", 125);
```

EDIT

Your config settings are simply appSettings that the original developer of YOUR code put in.
They are NOT code that your library knows about.

You most likely will have to create a new setting.

```
  <add key="PortNumber" value="125"/>
```

You will have to READ that value in your code.

And I think you'll have to change the call to the overloaded method

```
.Connect(host, portNumberIReadFromTheAppSetting);
```

You have to build the bridge.....

Comment: the host settings are in web.config without any port settings.

Comment: Post your relevant web.config entries.  Because if it is just some app-key-value pairs, you'll have to write some code.

Comment: here is the web.config config:


<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ConStr" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=email;server=172.31.2.24"/>
  <add key="ConStr3" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=123;server=172.31.2.24"/>
  <add key="ConStr2" value="uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=abc;server=cms"/>
  <add key="host" value="pop.mail.com"/>
  <add key="username" value="contact@mail.com"/>
  <add key="password" value="Password"/>
  <add key="from" value="Help Desk"/>
  <add key="from_email" value="contact@mail.com"/>

Comment: and here is the link to my mail.xml file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BFUnMd_tRGeWhTTF9mZWJfdVU/edit?usp=sharing